# installing hadoop 2.3 on mac osx

Tags: java, macos, hadoop, java-home

i used the following tutorials to install hadoop on macos: [Hadoop Tutorial 1](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-hadoop-on-ubuntu-13-10), [Hadoop Tutorial 2](http://blog.tundramonkey.com/2013/02/24/setting-up-hadoop-on-osx-mountain-lion)

when i trie to format the namenode i get the following error:

```
hdfs namenode -format
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode
```

i wonder, because i have set my java home to:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

here also my ~/.profile file:

```
#Hadoop variables
echo 'set hadoop variables'
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home
export HADOOP_INSTALL=/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.3.0
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/sbin
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
```

and my hadoop-env.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Copyright 2011 The Apache Software Foundation
# 
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
# or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
# distributed with this work for additional information
# regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
# to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
# "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
# with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# Set Hadoop-specific environment variables here.

# The only required environment variable is JAVA_HOME.  All others are
# optional.  When running a distributed configuration it is best to
# set JAVA_HOME in this file, so that it is correctly defined on
# remote nodes.

# The java implementation to use.
export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home)"

# The jsvc implementation to use. Jsvc is required to run secure datanodes.
#export JSVC_HOME=${JSVC_HOME}

export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=${HADOOP_CONF_DIR:-"/etc/hadoop"}

# Extra Java CLASSPATH elements.  Automatically insert capacity-scheduler.
for f in $HADOOP_HOME/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar; do
  if [ "$HADOOP_CLASSPATH" ]; then
    export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:$f
  else
    export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$f
  fi
done

# The maximum amount of heap to use, in MB. Default is 1000.
#export HADOOP_HEAPSIZE=
#export HADOOP_NAMENODE_INIT_HEAPSIZE=""

# Extra Java runtime options.  Empty by default.
export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"

# Command specific options appended to HADOOP_OPTS when specified
export HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS="-Dhadoop.security.logger=${HADOOP_SECURITY_LOGGER:-INFO,RFAS} -Dhdfs.audit.logger=${HDFS_AUDIT_LOGGER:-INFO,NullAppender} $HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS"
export HADOOP_DATANODE_OPTS="-Dhadoop.security.logger=ERROR,RFAS $HADOOP_DATANODE_OPTS"

export HADOOP_SECONDARYNAMENODE_OPTS="-Dhadoop.security.logger=${HADOOP_SECURITY_LOGGER:-INFO,RFAS} -Dhdfs.audit.logger=${HDFS_AUDIT_LOGGER:-INFO,NullAppender} $HADOOP_SECONDARYNAMENODE_OPTS"

# The following applies to multiple commands (fs, dfs, fsck, distcp etc)
export HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS="-Xmx512m $HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS"
#HADOOP_JAVA_PLATFORM_OPTS="-XX:-UsePerfData $HADOOP_JAVA_PLATFORM_OPTS"

# On secure datanodes, user to run the datanode as after dropping privileges
export HADOOP_SECURE_DN_USER=${HADOOP_SECURE_DN_USER}

# Where log files are stored.  $HADOOP_HOME/logs by default.
#export HADOOP_LOG_DIR=${HADOOP_LOG_DIR}/$USER

# Where log files are stored in the secure data environment.
export HADOOP_SECURE_DN_LOG_DIR=${HADOOP_LOG_DIR}/${HADOOP_HDFS_USER}

# The directory where pid files are stored. /tmp by default.
# NOTE: this should be set to a directory that can only be written to by 
#       the user that will run the hadoop daemons.  Otherwise there is the
#       potential for a symlink attack.
export HADOOP_PID_DIR=${HADOOP_PID_DIR}
export HADOOP_SECURE_DN_PID_DIR=${HADOOP_PID_DIR}

# A string representing this instance of hadoop. $USER by default.
export HADOOP_IDENT_STRING=$USER
```

my java version is:

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b132)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.0-b70, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command is:

```
hadoop namenode -format
```

And not:

```
hdfs namenode -format
```

By the way, since you are on Mac OSX; you can use Homebrew package manager to install Hadoop.

Comment: @Gerald If the answer is what you are looking for, then kindly you can pick it as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

The command you said was incorrect is actually valid. The one that was given instead is deprecated (but still works).

Comment: This answer doesn't really answer the question asked. Helpful information like reasons for why the config is not working etc would be helpful.

Comment: i have created a hadoop install script for osx, please let me know if someone is interested in.

Comment: @Gerald: it would be nice if you could share this script. Is it available somewhere?

Comment: there we go: https://github.com/geraldstanje/hadoop ... u might edit the script and change the version number ...

Comment: please vote my answer, if you find this script useful. thanks